# Money in SQL Server

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework-4

Im using entity framework as ORM and Sql Server 2008 as server.

I have financial operations in my app so that I used money column. But when result is for example 2.99986 it stores in database value 2.9998 while desired is 2.9999.

Is there any option to make it make it work just like math says and if not how can I round numbers in C# so that Math.Round(2.99986) would give as the result 2.9998, simply cuts the rest of sigits after 4th place.

Thanks for help

The only solution I came up with is to multiply my number by 10000 then truncate it and then divide by 10000 :) 
Any other better solutions ?

Comment: Usually you want as much precision as possible when performing financial calculations. Why do you want *less*?

Comment: Because often you don't want *precision*, you want *accuracy*. You do it the same way across your entire enterprise, otherwise you get penny-rounding errors that make accountants' heads explode. If another system is tracking similar numbers to 4 decimal places, you avoid a HUGE headache by simply doing it the same way.

Comment: Your 2nd and 3rd paragraphs after `hello` are in conflict. The 2nd says desired is 2.9999. Third says desired is 2.9998. The edit (last paragraph) says desired is 2.9998.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this to effectively truncate on the required precision

```
 Math.Round(value - 0.00005, 4, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero));
```

Answer (score 7):

That's a limit of the datatype. Looks like it truncates anything after the 4th digit to the right of the decimal.

From MSDN - [Using Monetary Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188688.aspx):

> If an object is defined as money, it can contain a maximum of 19 digits, 4 of which can be to the right of the decimal. The object uses 8 bytes to store the data. The money data type therefore has a precision of 19, a scale of 4, and a length of 8.

And:

> money and smallmoney are limited to four decimal points. Use the decimal data type if more decimal points are required.

---

Update:

From your comments it appears that  you want to resolve this in C#. In that case, you can use one of the [`Math.Round`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.round.aspx) overloads that takes a [`MidpointRounding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.midpointrounding.aspx) enumeration that suites the rounding logic that you need.

Comment: I dont need more decimal points. I just want to know what method Use to have In C# form number 2.99986 after rounding number 2.9998